# How to include model in belongstToMany relation in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I want to add in my sequelize query model, but i don't know how to do this correctly.

I have two tables: `Regions` and `Countries`. There is a relation between them called `belongsToMany` that is going through the table `region_countries`, there i have foreign keys `region_id` and `country_id`. For `Region` and `Countries` i have table with translation, for example: table `translate_trgions` has region and language_code name (en, fr, ru, etc.). And i am getting list of `regions` with `countries` with their translations.

**My Region model**

```js
class Region extends Model {}
Region.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
  },
  { sequelize, timestamps: false, tableName: 'regions', modelName: 'Region' }
);

class RegionTranslate extends Model {}
RegionTranslate.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    region_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      references: {
        model: Region,
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
    language_code: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      references: {
        model: Language,
        key: 'code',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'regions_description',
    modelName: 'RegionTranslate',
  }
);

class RegionsCountries extends Model {}
RegionsCountries.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    region_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      references: {
        model: Region,
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
    country_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      references: {
        model: Country,
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'region_countries',
    modelName: 'RegionsCountries',
  }
);

Region.hasMany(RegionTranslate, {
  foreignKey: 'region_id',
  as: 'translate_regions',
});
RegionTranslate.belongsTo(Region, { foreignKey: 'region_id' });

Region.belongsToMany(Country, {
  through: RegionsCountries,
  foreignKey: 'region_id',
});
Country.belongsToMany(Region, {
  through: RegionsCountries,
  foreignKey: 'country_id',
});

Region.belongsToMany(CountryTranslate, {
  through: RegionsCountries,
  as: 'translate_countries',
  foreignKey: 'country_id',
  otherKey: 'id',
});
```

**My Country Model**

```js
class Country extends Model {}
Country.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    code: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    unicode: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  { sequelize, timestamps: false, tableName: 'countries', modelName: 'Country' }
);

class CountryTranslate extends Model {}
CountryTranslate.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    language_code: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: Language,
        key: 'code',
      },
    },
    country_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: Country,
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'countries_description',
    modelName: 'CountryTranslate',
  }
);

Country.hasMany(CountryTranslate, {
  foreignKey: 'country_id',
  as: 'translate_countries',
});
CountryTranslate.belongsTo(Country, { foreignKey: 'country_id' });

Country.belongsToMany(Region, {
  through: RegionsCountries,
  foreignKey: 'country_id',
});
```

**My query in RegionController**

```js
const regions = await Region.findAll({
  attributes: {
    include: [[Sequelize.literal('translate_regions.name'), 'name']],
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: Country,
      attributes: {
        include: [[Sequelize.literal('translate_countries.name'), 'name']],
      },
      through: {
        attributes: [],
      },
    },
    {
      model: RegionTranslate,
      as: 'translate_regions',
      where: { language_code: language },
      attributes: [],
    },
    {
      model: CountryTranslate,
      as: 'translate_countries',
    },
  ],
});
```

**The output i'm getting**

```json
"regions": [
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Europe",
    "Countries": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "code": "dza",
        "unicode": "12",
        "name": "Ангола"
      }
    ],
    "translate_countries": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "language_code": "ru",
        "country_id": 5,
        "name": "Ангола",
        "description": null,
        "RegionsCountries": {
          "id": 10,
          "region_id": 4,
          "country_id": 4
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**The output that i want**

```json
"regions": [
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Europe",
    "Countries": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "code": "and",
        "unicode": "20",
        "name": "Andorra"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting up your Model associations for many-to-many through a relational table, you need to specify the columns in the relational table that is the foreign key for your source table primary key, as well as the column that is the "other" foreign key for the related table primary key. It's helpful to specify an `as` property as well to identify the relationship.

This is an example, check other relationships as well.

```js
// use otherKey to indicate the relationship
// country.id -> country_id, region_id -> region.id
Country.belongsToMany(Region, {
  as: 'regions',
  through: RegionsCountries,
  foreignKey: 'country_id',
  otherKey: 'region_id'
});
```

When you query for related records we can no specify the `through` and `as` property on the query.

```js
Country.findByPk(countryId, {
  include: [{
    model: Region,
    through: RegionsCountries,
    as: 'regions',
  }],
});
```